# Autoreload of modules in IPython

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Is there a way to have IPython automatically reload all changed code? Either before each line is executed in the shell or failing that when it is specifically requested to. I'm doing a lot of exploratory programming using IPython and SciPy and it's quite a pain to have to manually reload each module whenever I change it.

Comment: Here it's implemented as an extension http://projects.scipy.org/ipython/ipython/ticket/154

Comment: You might consider changing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 548, accepted):

For IPython version 3.1, 4.x, and 5.x

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Then your module will be **auto-reloaded** by default. This is the doc:

```
File:       ...my/python/path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions/autoreload.py

Docstring:
``autoreload`` is an IPython extension that reloads modules
automatically before executing the line of code typed.

This makes for example the following workflow possible:

.. sourcecode:: ipython

   In [1]: %load_ext autoreload

   In [2]: %autoreload 2

   In [3]: from foo import some_function

   In [4]: some_function()
   Out[4]: 42

   In [5]: # open foo.py in an editor and change some_function to return 43

   In [6]: some_function()
   Out[6]: 43

The module was reloaded without reloading it explicitly, and the
object imported with ``from foo import ...`` was also updated.
```

There is a trick: when you **forget all** of the above when using `ipython`, just  try:

```
import autoreload
?autoreload
# Then you get all the above
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in `ipdb`? Say, I am in ipd, and I notice a line didnt work. So I changed the line, and want to reload the file. Will this work?

Comment: An improvement to the first line first checks to see if autoreload has already been loaded: `if 'autoreload' not in get_ipython().extension_manager.loaded:\n
    %load_ext autoreload\n
%autoreload 2`. This will get rid of the following error that appears when executing the command again: `The autoreload extension is already loaded. To reload it, use:\n
  %reload_ext autoreload`.

Comment: What does 2 in `%autoreload 2` mean?

Comment: the `2` in `%autoreload 2` means `Reload all modules (except those excluded by %aimport) every time before executing the Python code typed.`

https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html

Comment: If you want this set automatically on every session in PyCharm, you can add it to the startup script in Settings → Buld, Execution, Deployment → Console → Python Console → Startup Script. You must use a Conda interpreter to get it to work in PyCharm.

Comment: I'm coming here every single time I have to do this. They are two lines that I cannot / don't want to remember

Comment: Same here @JuanLuisRuiz-tagle, about 5 years googling and coming to this thread haha

Answer (score 122):

As mentioned above, you need the `autoreload` extension. If you want it to automatically start every time you launch `ipython`, you need to add it to the `ipython_config.py` startup file:

It may be necessary to generate one first:

```
ipython profile create
```

Then include these lines in `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = []
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines.append('%load_ext autoreload')
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines.append('%autoreload 2')
```

As well as an optional warning in case you need to take advantage of compiled Python code in `.pyc` files:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines.append('print("Warning: disable autoreload in ipython_config.py to improve performance.")')
```

edit: the above works with version 0.12.1 and 0.13

Comment: This is actually great. I was wondering why no one else was posting solutions to preserve it. Does this work with older versions of IPython as well? I've been using 0.12+. I recall that the way ipython stores customizations changed significantly.

Comment: I'm using 0.12.1, and haven't yet tried 0.13, so I don't know whether it will work with 0.13+

Comment: This is a good approach, but I think all you need to do is fill in the extenstions which should be around line 27: 
`c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']`

Comment: use `c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']`, 
and `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']`. I am not sure but in the default profile of version 0.13 under Ubuntu 13.04 I found a 'startup' folder that contains a script '50_autoreload.ipy' to activate autoreload. Maybe nothing is required at all

Comment: I have to find this answer on any new install, this is the only sane config for development in iPython.

Comment: This file doesnt seem to be there by default so you might have to create it as he said.  Also before the code add ...

c = get_config()  #Should be first line

Comment: Is this still needed for ipython 1.2.1.?  And 3.0.0?

Comment: Since `--pylab` is not longer an option I use `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2', '%pylab']`

Answer (score 69):

REVISED - please see Andrew_1510's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10472712/12892) below, as IPython has been updated.

...

It was a bit hard figure out how to get there from a dusty bug report, but:

It ships with IPython now!

```
import ipy_autoreload
%autoreload 2
%aimport your_mod

# %autoreload? for help
```

... then every time you call `your_mod.dwim()`, it'll pick up the latest version.

Comment: What if it is less direct? `%run sometest.py` contains `import themod`. After editing `themod.py`, I'd like to just `%run sometest.py`, but it doesn't pick up the changes.

Comment: I think ipython 0.11 did away with this feature. Or is it just renamed/hidden someplace?

Comment: SirVer, you're right.  Sigh.

Evidently, it's in the 'quarantine' package:
http://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/ipython/files/

Comment: Explanation [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/whatsnew/version0.11.html#quarantine) - with an invitation to port to 0.11 :)

'from IPython.quarantine import ipy_autoreload' succeeds, and creates an %autoreload command... but in my initial tests, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Looks like it's back in as of 9/30/2011 - so maybe we'll see it in an upcoming release.

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/746

Comment: What if I wanted to do "from moduleX import blah"?

Comment: @exfizik, IIUC, I think you need `%aimport moduleX` and then (on a subsequent line in the notebook) `from moduleX import blah`

Answer (score 15):

If you add file *ipython_config.py* into the ~/.ipython/profile_default directory with lines like below, then the autoreload functionality will be loaded on IPython startup (tested on 2.0.0):

```
print "--------->>>>>>>> ENABLE AUTORELOAD <<<<<<<<<------------"

c = get_config()
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = []
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines.append('%load_ext autoreload')
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines.append('%autoreload 2')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
  import ipy_autoreload
  %autoreload 2 
  %aimport your_mod
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for that, but I have no usage experience yet:

http://ipython.scipy.org/ipython/ipython/attachment/ticket/154/ipy_autoreload.py