# How can I reload objects in my namespace in ipython

Tags: python, ipython

After import functions into ipython, how do I reload them when I have modified them outside of ipython ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Python 2:

```
reload(module)
```

Python 3:

```
from importlib import reload
reload(module)
```

Where `module` is the file with your functions.

Comment: This is correct. However, reload() does not automatically recurse to imports-of-imports, so if you modify something that is imported indirectly, it won't get reloaded.

Comment: @Amber Yes, that's a limitation. You can do `x = module.x` or a function which does that for you if you need to rebind those names

Comment: Or you can just `reload(sys.modules['foo_module'])` to reload `foo_module`.

Comment: @Amber: IPython actually offers a `dreload` function which works recursively.

Comment: python3 need to do `from importlib import reload` first

Answer (score 6):

you can also use autoreload, so that the modules you are working on are automatically reloaded at each statement, pretty handy for debugging, see:

[Autoreload of modules in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907993/autoreload-of-modules-in-ipython)

Answer (score 3):

Use the following link to read more about [reload](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/functions.html?highlight=all#reload) built-in function. Please find sample below:

```
import controls.grid
reload(controls.grid)
```

Note that reload is *'Reload a previously imported module. The argument must be a module object, so it must have been successfully imported before.'* and *'When a module is reloaded, its dictionary (containing the module’s global variables) is retained. Redefinitions of names will override the old definitions, so this is generally not a problem. If the new version of a module does not define a name that was defined by the old version, the old definition remains.'*