# IPython doesn't reload code when running in the QTConsole

Tags: python, qt, ipython

I'm running `ipython qtconsole`. I want to execute a file that I edit separately inside an editor. When I make changes to the file in the editor and re-run it in IPython using:

```
%run myfile.py
```

the code isn't updated. However, if I run `ipython` normally from the terminal then this works fine. I tried to use `autoreload` in the QT console:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload
```

but it doesn't fix the problem. What is wrong here?

Comment: I can't reproduce. If I edit the file, save it and re-run, the code is updated. Can you post more information on your ipython/qtconsole version, your code and your editor ?

Answer (score 1):

did you try:

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(<module_name>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the general python reload instead of the ipython autoreload like:

`reload(module)`

Bear in mind that this will not automatically reload dependencies, so you would have reload any nested imports as well.

[See this question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6420389/9101283)