# ipython %load_ext missing

Tags: python, reload, ipython

I try to set autoreload to my development process, but it seems, that the method I learned from [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython) thread is not working with my versions.
I tried

1. ipython -V: 0.10 and python -V Python 2.6.6
2. ipython -V: 0.10.1 and python -V Python 2.7.3

but

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

returns

```
ERROR: Magic function `load_ext` not found.
```

which is kind of obvious, because

```
In [1]: %lsmagic
Available magic functions:
%Exit  %Pprint  %Quit  %alias  %autocall  %autoindent  %automagic  %bg  %bookmark  %cd          %clear  %color_info  %colors  %cpaste  %debug  %dhist  %dirs  %doctest_mode  %ed  %edit  %env      %exit  %hist  %history  %logoff  %logon  %logstart  %logstate  %logstop  %lsmagic  %macro  %magic  %p  %page  %paste  %pdb  %pdef  %pdoc  %pfile  %pinfo  %popd  %profile  %prun  %psearch  %psource  %pushd  %pwd  %pycat  %quickref  %quit  %r  %rehash  %rehashx  %rep  %reset  %run  %runlog  %save  %sc  %store  %sx  %system_verbose  %time  %timeit  %unalias  %upgrade  %who  %who_ls  %whos  %xmode
```

this method is not available. How can I install other magic functions?

Comment: You can't install new ipython?

Comment: which one should I install? my easy_install says `sudo easy_install ipython

Searching for ipython
Best match: ipython 0.10.1
`

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907993/autoreload-of-modules-in-ipython), `%autoreload` is in the [quarantine directory](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/whatsnew/version0.11.html#quarantine) of ipython 0.11, and fully available in version 0.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Current Install**

In your current install, can you try:-

```
import ipy_autoreload
```

and see what you get?

**New Install**

Can you attempt to reinstall `IPython` with

```
pip install ipython
```

(for a local install if you are using virtualenv) or

```
sudo pip install ipython
```

if you are install your `IPython` system-wide.

And because `pip install` doesn't deal with sys path properly if you are on Mac OSX, you might need to do

```
easy_install -a readline   # `sudo easy_install -a readline` for system-wide install of course.
```

(if you are using Mac OSX)

If you have the latest `IPython`, you should see `IPython 0.13.1` when you first load up the shell. And you shouldn't have any problems with `%load_ext autoreload` then.

Comment: thanks, that worked fine! I also needed to correct my ipython shell script as described here: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30702 . now I got IPython 0.13.1 running. Thanks a lot

Comment: Cool. I see you use `macports` too. Glad to be of service.  I am a `macports` user myself and may I suggest that you use `macports` for non-python libraries but focus on using `pip` to directly install python-related libraries.  It will save you a lot of headache. And `pypi` (which is where `pip` grabs the source code), will usually have more updated versions of a python library compared to `macports`.

Comment: maybe I was to straightforward to change my startscript, It seems, that now, I can only import modules placed in the /opt/local/bin/ipython directory: `In [9]: ls` returns
`a.py` but `In [10]: from a import *
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/local/bin/ipython in <module>()
----> 1 from a import *

ImportError: No module named a`. It looks like ipython has now some path issues

Comment: run in your `IPython` the following
`import sys`;
`sys.path`
and paste the output in a pastebin. (pastebin.com)

Comment: sys.path outputs a bunch of directories, but normally the directory I start ipython should be part of it? doesn't seem so. Same problem afterwards

Comment: Yes. The directory that you start your `ipython` should have part of `sys.path`.  Here's mine as an example: http://dpaste.com/825687/

As you can see from the paste, `''` is in the list and therefore the current directory (which I start ipython shell from) is in the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: `import sys; sys.path; sys.path.append("/Users/millawell/mydir") ` works.

Comment: Yes, if you have a custom directory which ipython isn't aware of (not in `PYTHONPATH`), you will need to specifically append it as you have done.