# Why is iPython notebook interpreting commented out lines?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This question is not about a specific error---the error arrises because I'm using `matplotlib`'s `tight_layout` incorrectly.

I want to know why iPython is interpreting a line of code that I have commented out--or, rather, under what circumstances this is expected to happen (i.e., I need to relaunch the kernel, or whatever).

The error seems to persist, in spite of the fact that I re-executed the relevant imports.

Code:

```
import forecasting_report.analyze as fcst_rprt
analysis = fcst_rprt.ForecastingReport()
analysis.analyze()
results = analysis.user_dict
```

Error says:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a62e6e8717be> in <module>()
      1 analysis = fcst_rprt.ForecastingReport()
----> 2 analysis.analyze()
      3 results = analysis.user_dict

/Users/[...]/ForecastingReport/forecasting_report/analyze.py in analyze(self)  
     44         self.breakdown = help.breakdown(self.user_dict)
---> 45         #plots.plot_breakdown(self.breakdown, self.path)
     46 
     47     def write_results(self):

<Error Stack continues>
```

---

Note:

A perfectly fine answer is : "That's just not the way it works". To be sure, I haven't tried to reproduce this error at the command line, so it just may be my ignorance of the Python interpreter.

Comment: have you tried restarting the notebook

Comment: Yes--that seems to fix the problem. I just don't know why the `import` statement doesn't pick up changes to the module.

Comment: in the past, i've noticed that if I installed a module, it wouldn't automatically become available, a restart is needed.

Comment: Python will only import a module once, if you need to reload it somewhere, you can use: `reload(module_name)`

Comment: @babalu: is this true in the interpreter as well? Or just the notebook?

Comment: @DaveChallis: So simply re-issuing the `import` statement is not enough?

Comment: Yup, I believe python will see that the module has already been imported, and do nothing, regardless of whether the module has been modified since.

Comment: @DaveChallis: Why don't you post that as an answer. Please :)

Comment: No problem, done now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python will only initialise an imported module once, further calls to `import` will have no effect, even if the module has been modified since being read.

To reload a module, use the builtin function [reload](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) on the already imported module object, e.g.:

```
import mymodule

# ...later...
reload(mymodule)
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

which should work with ipython terminal, i not sure if it works in ipython notebook. You can view help through `autoreload?` and this post: [Autoreload of modules in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907993/autoreload-of-modules-in-ipython)