# How to force IPython to see an updated library?

Tags: python, import, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I do the following in my IPython notebook:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('my_directory')
from db import *
```

It works fine. But then I added a new function to the `db.py` and IPython does not see it. It OK. But it does not see it even if I `reset` everything end re-execute the cell that imports everything. It does not see it even if I user reload. It does not see it even if I close the IPython notebook and restart it.

What is the way to force IPython (or python) to see the updated content of the file?

Comment: I think this is something you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907993/autoreload-of-modules-in-ipython

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use autoreload. Check the manual at http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/extensions/autoreload.html. Seems you need:

```
%autoreload 2
```

The above will automatically reload all imported modules. Except those inlcuded in a separate special list of modules specified by %aimport modulename. Those will only be autoreloaded if you specify %autoreload 1.