# Use of a newly installed egg module in an existing iPython session?

Tags: python, ipython

I wondered how one can get iPython to be aware of a newly installed egg-based module without restarting the session?

Using iPython's autoreload feature from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907993/autoreload-of-modules-in-ipython) does not seem to help.

One solution I found was to copy the module directory out of the egg directory and into the base site-packages folder and then iPython could import it. Otherwise I had to restart iPython so it would be able to load the relevant module. But this is not ideal as often I'm working in an iPython session and I don't want to lose alot of state just so I can load a new module.

Comment: Why would you do that? Install the package before running the session.

Comment: As I said I have alot of saved state in my iPython sessions which I typically keep running for days at a time.