# ipython notebooks sometimes not finding functions in file

Tags: python, function, import, jupyter-notebook

EDIT: This is *not* solved in [the suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907993/autoreload-of-modules-in-ipython); reloading the module 
after editing the file doesn't help.

I have a python file "/home/Misc/misc_def.py" collecting some functions that I'm using in several ipython notebooks. The first cell in each notebook is

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
sns.set_style('white')
from sys import path
path.append('/home/Misc')
import misc_def
```

However, the strange thing is that sometimes this works (the notebook can find the functions in the file) and sometimes it doesn't. I'm using notebooks in different folders, but I think this shouldn't matter since it's all absolute paths. The errors I get are standard for not finding functions; e.g.

```
NameError: name 'get_overlap_data' is not defined
```

Is there something unstable about the way I do it above?

Comment: Are you editing the file with the functions at the same time as the notebook?

Comment: I was; however I would save the function file before trying to use it. I now tried to close it completely before importing it, with the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autoreload of modules in IPython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907993/autoreload-of-modules-in-ipython)

Comment: @tmoreau reloading after changing the file does not help