# Plotted images show up grey

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

When running a soybean weed classifier, images are supposed to be displayed in this plot but they show up grey. No clue where to go from here.
Here's what the output is supposed to look like:

[image: Correct Output]

Here's what the code actually looks like:

[image: My Output]

Code:

1.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import cv2
import glob

# This is a bit of magic to make matplotlib figures appear inline in the notebook
# rather than in a new window.
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (19.0, 17.0) # set default size of plots
plt.rcParams['image.interpolation'] = 'nearest'
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'

# Some more magic so that the notebook will reload external python modules;
# see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907993/autoreload-of-modules-in-ipython
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

2.

```
data_dir = 'home/jack/Desktop/weed-detection-in-soybean-crops/dataset/dataset/'
classes = ['broadleaf', 'grass', 'soil', 'soybean'] 

num_file = 1100 
all_files = [] 
num_data =num_file*len(classes)
Y = np.zeros(num_data)


for i, cls in enumerate(classes):
    all_files += [f for f in glob.glob(data_dir+cls+'/*.tif')][:num_file]
    Y[i*num_file:(i+1)*num_file] = i # label all classes with int [0.. len(classes)]


# Image dimension
im_width = 200
im_height = 200 
im_channel = 3
dim = im_width * im_height * im_channel

X = np.ndarray(shape=(num_data, im_width, im_height, im_channel), dtype=np.float64)

for idx, file in enumerate(all_files):
    X[idx] = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(file), (im_width, im_height))

X_train = np.empty(shape=(4000,im_width, im_height, im_channel), dtype=np.float64)
X_val = np.empty(shape=(200,im_width, im_height, im_channel), dtype=np.float64)
X_test = np.empty(shape=(200,im_width, im_height, im_channel), dtype=np.float64)

y_train = np.empty(4000)
y_val = np.empty(200)
y_test = np.empty(200) 

for i, cls in enumerate(classes): 
    X_test[50*i:50*(i+1)] = X[np.where(Y == i)[0][:50]]
    X_val[50*i:50*(i+1)] = X[np.where(Y == i)[0][50:100]]
    X_train[1000*i:1000*(i+1)] = X[np.where(Y == i)[0][100:]]

    y_test[50*i:50*(i+1)] = i
    y_val[50*i:50*(i+1)] = i
    y_train[1000*i:1000*(i+1)] = i

del Y 
del X

# Extract features 
#Shuffle training index
train_idxs = np.random.permutation(X_train.shape[0])
y_train  = y_train[train_idxs].astype(int)
X_train = X_train[train_idxs]

X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], -1)).astype('float64')
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], -1)).astype('float64')
X_val = np.reshape(X_val, (X_val.shape[0], -1)).astype('float64')

X_tiny = X_train[100:110].astype('float64')
y_tiny = y_train[100:110].astype(int)
num_dev = 500

X_dev = X_train[0:num_dev].astype('float64')
y_dev = y_train[0:num_dev].astype(int)
print("X_train shape", X_train.shape, "| y_train shape:", y_train.shape)
print("X_test shape", X_test.shape, "| y_test shape:", y_test.shape)
print("X_val shape", X_val.shape, "| y_val shape:", y_val.shape)
print("X_dev shape", X_dev.shape, "| y_dev shape:", y_dev.shape)
print("X_tiny shape", X_tiny.shape, "| y_tiny shape:", y_tiny.shape)

#Subtract out the mean image 
#first: compute the mean image
# mean_image = np.mean(X_train, axis=0) #axis=0. stack horizontally
mean_image = 128
#Second subtract the mean image from train and test data 
X_train -= mean_image
X_val -= mean_image 
X_test -= mean_image
X_dev -= mean_image
X_tiny -= mean_image

#Third append the bias dimension using linear algebra trick
#Not for net
# X_train = np.hstack([X_train, np.ones((X_train.shape[0], 1))])
# X_val = np.hstack([X_val, np.ones((X_val.shape[0], 1))])
# X_test = np.hstack([X_test, np.ones((X_test.shape[0], 1))])
# X_dev = np.hstack([X_dev, np.ones((X_dev.shape[0], 1))])
# X_tiny = np.hstack([X_tiny, np.ones((X_tiny.shape[0], 1))])

print('=====STACK BIAS term=====')
print("X_train shape", X_train.shape)
print("X_test shape", X_test.shape)
print("X_val shape", X_val.shape)
print("X_dev shape", X_dev.shape)
print("X_tiny shape", X_tiny.shape)
```

3.

```
# Visualize some images 
# Make sure that everything when OK
classes = ['broadleaf', 'grass', 'soil', 'soybean']
n_class = len(classes)
samples_per_class = 4


for y, cls in enumerate(classes):
    idxes = np.flatnonzero(y == y_train)
    idxes = np.random.choice(idxes, samples_per_class, replace = False)
    for i, idx in enumerate(idxes):
        plt_idx = i * n_class + y + 1
        plt.subplot(samples_per_class,n_class, plt_idx)
        plt.imshow(X_train[idx].reshape(im_width, im_height, im_channel).astype('uint8'))
        if(i==0): plt.title(cls)

plt.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've looked all over but can't find anything referencing this. Thanks.

Comment: Far tl;dr, but if the should look like _(some colorful little pictures)_ this is imo in contrast with `plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'`

Answer (score 0):

When making the plots, you change the dtype to `uint8`... did you try not doing that? If they are small floats, you're going to end up with a lot of zeros.

In other words, try changing the third-from-last line into:

```
plt.imshow(X_train[idx].reshape(im_width, im_height, im_channel))\
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the "data_dir" path correctly. Instead of setting path as

```
data_dir = 'home/jack/Desktop/weed-detection-in-soybean-crops/dataset/dataset/'
```

use

```
data_dir = r'/home/jack/Desktop/weed-detection-in-soybean-crops/dataset/dataset/'
```

to get correct path type "pwd".