# Jupyter does not see changes in the imported module

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a file called "Notebook.ipynb". I want to import my own module into it patterns.py. Let's say in patterns.py I have a variable `a=1`. If I print it in Jupyter after importing it, I expect to get 1. But if I change the value of the variable to patterns.py Jupyter will continue to think that the variable `a` is equal to one. At the same time, of course, I restart the cell in which the variable is imported from patterns.py

What do I need to do to make Jupyter understand that the value of the variable has changed?

Answer (score 9):

There's actually a nifty IPython extension for this called [autoreload](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html).  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10472712/9986591) shows how to use it in an IPython shell, but you can do the same in a Jupyter notebook.  Just add:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

before you import the module whose changes you want to have tracked, and it'll be re-imported before every cell you execute.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose we have a file at `folder_name/filename.py` and call it in some .ipynb

```py
def some_func():
    print("test")
```

which was modified like this

```py
def some_func():
    print("test2")
```

In this case, **second** call of the following code in .ipynb

```py
import folder_name.filename as module_name
module_name.some_func()
```

returns `test`

To update the function, you need to reload the module:

```py
importlib.reload(module_name)
# you can reload "folder_name.filename" if you do not use molude name alias
module_name.some_func()
```

This code will return `test2` 
Don't forget to `import importlib` before you run `reload`

Answer (score 4):

This has happened to me.

You need to restart the python kernel so jupyter can read the new state of the python scripts located in the working directory.

Then the variable `a` should print the new assigned value.

Comment: Do I need to do this every time I make a change?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Answer (score 2):

Just in addition to @ilia post:
Let's say the module's name is main.py
That's the code I put in the Jupiter's notebook cell, just before calling functions from the main module

```
import importlib
imported_module = importlib.import_module("main")
importlib.reload(imported_module)
from main import *
```