# How do I fix the 'No module named numpy' error when importing it in Anaconda Python?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' on mac

Hello,
I've already dowloaded anaconda in my macbook, but when I try to run the session:

```
# Numpy is the main package for scientific computing with Python.
import numpy as np


#from skimage import io


# Imports all the methods we define in the file a1code.py
from a1code import *


# Matplotlib is a useful plotting library for python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# This code is to make matplotlib figures appear inline in the
# notebook rather than in a new window.
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10.0, 8.0) # set default size of plots
plt.rcParams['image.interpolation'] = 'nearest'
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'


# Some more magic so that the notebook will reload external python modules;
# see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907993/autoreload-of-modules-in-ipython
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
%reload_ext autoreload
```

I got the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 2 1
# Numpy is the main package for scientific computing with Python. ----> 2 import numpy as np 4
#from skimage import io 5 6
# Imports all the methods we define in the file a1code.py 7 from a1code import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

but I downloaded numpy:

```
python -m pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/yuqingchen/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.23.5)
```

and I also used the command line: conda install numpy

but it doesn't work for me

I am not sure which part cause this error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you `pip install`ing from the same conda environment as you're running your notebook?

Comment: Yes I think I did. I checked the environment and it's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify the install first with below command.

```
conda list numpy
```

Then if you dont see the numpy module, install it using below command.

```
conda install numpy
```

Then activate your conda environment to make sure it reflects the change.

```
conda activate <your_environment_name>
```

Then import your package in code.

```
import numpy
```

Good luck!